# Getting error while dereferencing a list in loop

Tags: python, dereference

I am trying to reference a list(reclist) and appending it to another list(data) but when i try to dereference it i get following error. Is this method wrong Or how can i fix this error?

```
import gc
def deref(id_):
    return next(ob for ob in gc.get_objects() if id(ob) == id_)

reclist = []
data = []

for j in range(10):
    reclist  = ["ID", "A", "C", 3535325]
    ref = id(reclist)
    data.append(ref)      # loading reference

for rec in data:
    output = deref(rec)
    print(output)
```

Error Messgae:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ref_deref.py", line 14, in <module>
    output = deref(rec)             
  File "ref_deref.py", line 3, in deref
    return next(ob for ob in gc.get_objects() if id(ob) == id_)
StopIteration
```

Comment: Why would those temporary lists still all exist?

Comment: are you referring to recllist?

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers, so I'm at a loss by what you mean by "dereference".

Comment: Why are you appending `id`s to `data`? Why not just append the list? Why are you trying to do things this way?

Comment: You really should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because you're not wrapping `deref` to handle `StopIteration` exception:

```
def deref(id_):
    try:
        return next(ob for ob in gc.get_objects() if id(ob) == id_)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Output:

```
None
['ID', 'A', 'C', 3535325]
[]
['ID', 'A', 'C', 3535325]
[]
['ID', 'A', 'C', 3535325]
[]
['ID', 'A', 'C', 3535325]
[]
['ID', 'A', 'C', 3535325]
```

Comment: ok but why it is printing None and [] it is supposed to produce 10 list.

Comment: Note that this didn't actually "dereference" five of of the original ten lists: those are all references to a single list, which happened to have the same id as four previous lists.  Once an object is disposed, its address is immediately available for reuse, making any recovery of the original object impossible.

Comment: @jasonharper is there any way to print all 10 list?

Comment: @Manish: No, of course not.  They *no longer exist*.

Comment: @Manish, if you track the `id` being passed to `deref` with a set, you'll see a small subset being presented to it: in my case it was `{4310765648, 4310765888}`. This is because of what @jasonharper mentioned above. Also, I believe your question had to do with the `StopIteration`, not specifically how to do the job in question.

Comment: @jasonharper my whole idea is to store the reference of list rather than actual list to save memory and time. In perl and C it can be implemented using references.

Comment: @Manish **that makes no sense**. Everything in python already acts as a reference. `list` objects internally are essentially primitive arrays of `PyObject` pointers. If anything, this will be *more* memory intensive because you are creating a bunch of unnecessary `int` objects. And certainly, it would be *slower*. **Python isn't C**

Comment: @jasonharper Any way to make it mo memory efficient?

Comment: @Manish it's as memory efficient as it could possibly be. I think you fundamentally don't understand how Python works. When you put an object in a list, you don't copy the object.

Comment: @Manish, if you somehow managed to avoid the memory use of the contents of the list, then you obviously no longer have the contents of the list.

Comment: @jasonharper I think the OP believes Python objects and lists work sort of like C primitive arrays and structs. They do not.

Comment: @Manish "to save memory and time" - that's comedy gold :-)

Comment: @Algebra8 Any idea how you got `[]` instead of `None`?

Comment: @superb brain it's because of the pass - `deref` returns `None`. `id(ob) == id_` doesn't exist in `gc.get_objects()` on the first iteration. Why? I'm not sure yet, but it's interesting. What's also interesting is if you print  `data` right before the `for rec in data` loop, you'll get an empty list instead of `None`.

Comment: I understand the `None`, and I actually get it five times (instead of your once and then four empty lists). I just don't understand the empty list. Have you tried it multiple times and it always looked like that? And what do you mean it's because of the `pass`? That doesn't create a list.

Comment: Uh... I ran it on a different computer now and got one `None` and then four times `[752]`. Wat. The code never created that. Neither that list, nor even that number. I guess the lesson is to just not pick random things from the garbage :-)